# Regular expression to match a sample shortcode

Tags: php, regex

I need help with a PHP regular expression that would match the sample shortcode below:

```
[smiley set_name="Happy" filename="smiling.gif"]
```

I'd like to extract "Happy" and "smiling.gif" from the above shortcode. I would highly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's in wordpress, you can get those attributes from its Shortcode handler: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much of your string you can assume to know but maybe something like:

```
/\[smiley set_name="([\w\s]+)" filename="(\w+.gif|jpg|png|jpeg)"\]/
```

So your code may look like:

```
$string = '[smiley set_name="Happy" filename="smiling.gif"]';

preg_match('/\[smiley set_name="([\w\s]+)" filename="(\w+.gif|jpg|png|jpeg)"\]/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: If you are not sure about the string then how about: `(?<=set_name=")([^"]+)|(?<=filename=")([^"]+)` ? ? ?

Comment: Because he asked in the question title "expression to match sample shortcode". The regex you've given doesn't match the shortcode, it only extracts the data. Kudos for the regex though.

Comment: Thanks @DrRoach, I tried your name and it worked. One last thing, set_name does not match spaces. If I have "Happy Faces" instead of "Happy", it doesn't get extracted.

Comment: @xcoder Changed my answer so that it'll now match for spaces too. Hope that's what you were after